# How to get the northern hemisphere SCF from polar Perspective

Tags: google-earth-engine

I got the SCF (snow cover frequency) trend chart in gee. How to get the Arctic view like the following figure and the trend similar to the figure below. The trend chart obtained in GEE is a point, while the figure below is a block.Need to export to ArcGIS for operation? Need to choose RGB type when exporting?
here is my code link:https://code.earthengine.google.com/73df83507fa504e4735d4d30dd02b15c

[image]
[image]